# Xamarin Android: Exception thrown when adding new ImageView to ViewFlipper

Tags: android, xamarin, viewflipper

This is my first Xamarin project. I'm trying to create a simple slideshow app for Android.

Here's the Main.axml code that hosts the ViewFlipper.

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical">
    <ViewFlipper
        android:id="@+id/view_flipper"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent">
    </ViewFlipper>
</RelativeLayout>
```

Here's the Activity code.

```
namespace RS
{
    [assembly: UsesPermission(Android.Manifest.Permission.Internet)]
    [Activity (Label = "RS", MainLauncher = true)]
    public class MainActivity : Activity
    {
        protected override void OnCreate (Bundle bundle)
        {
            base.OnCreate (bundle);

            // Set our view from the "main" layout resource
            SetContentView (Resource.Layout.Main);

            StartSlideshow (this);
        }

        private Bitmap GetImageBitmapFromUrl(string url)
        {
            Bitmap imageBitmap = null;

            url = url.Replace("\"", "");

            using (var webClient = new WebClient())
            {
                var imageBytes = webClient.DownloadData(url);
                if (imageBytes != null && imageBytes.Length > 0)
                {
                    imageBitmap = BitmapFactory.DecodeByteArray(imageBytes, 0, imageBytes.Length);
                }
            }

            return imageBitmap;
        }

        private void StartSlideshow(Context ctx) 
        {   
            string[] slides = null;
            string url = "http://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/photos";
            var httpReq = (HttpWebRequest)HttpWebRequest.Create (new Uri (url));

            httpReq.BeginGetResponse ((ar) => {

                //Fetch the slides
                var request = (HttpWebRequest)ar.AsyncState;
                using (var response = (HttpWebResponse)request.EndGetResponse (ar))     {                           
                    var s = response.GetResponseStream ();
                    var j = (JsonArray)JsonArray.Load (s);

                    //Prepare the slides
                    slides = (from result in j
                        select result ["url"].ToString ()).ToArray ();

                    //Display the slides
                    ViewFlipper mViewFlipper = FindViewById<ViewFlipper>(Resource.Id.view_flipper);

                    for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
                        ImageView image = new ImageView(ctx);
                        image.SetImageBitmap(GetImageBitmapFromUrl(slides[i]));
                        try {
                            mViewFlipper.AddView(image);                            
                        } catch (Exception ex) {
                            Log.Error(ex.ToString(), "Couldn't add image to flipper");
                        }
                    }

                    mViewFlipper.AutoStart = true;
                    mViewFlipper.SetFlipInterval (2000);
                    mViewFlipper.StartFlipping ();
                }
            } , httpReq);

        }
    }
}
```

When I try to add a new ImageView to the ViewFlipper (after I get the list of images to display from the web service call), I get the following error.

```
ex  {Android.Util.AndroidRuntimeException: Exception of type 'Android.Util.AndroidRuntimeException' was thrown.
  at Android.Runtime.JNIEnv.CallVoidMethod (IntPtr jobject, IntPtr jmethod, Android.Runtime.JValue[] parms) [0x00063] in /Users/builder/data/lanes/monodroid-mlion-monodroid-4.12-series/163212a9/source/monodroid/src/Mono.Android/src/Runtime/JNIEnv.g.cs:507 
  at Android.Views.ViewGroup.AddView (Android.Views.View child) [0x00043] in /Users/builder/data/lanes/monodroid-mlion-monodroid-4.12-series/163212a9/source/monodroid/src/Mono.Android/platforms/android-19/src/generated/Android.Views.ViewGroup.cs:1761 
  at RS.MainActivity+<>c__DisplayClass2.<StartSlideshow>b__0 (IAsyncResult ar) [0x000a0] in c:\Users\girish\Dropbox\Work\Rejini\android\RejiniSlider\RS\RS\MainActivity.cs:84 
  --- End of managed exception stack trace ---
android.view.ViewRootImpl$CalledFromWrongThreadException: Only the original thread that created a view hierarchy can touch its views.
    at android.view.ViewRootImpl.checkThread(ViewRootImpl.java:4039)
    at android.view.ViewRootImpl.requestLayout(ViewRootImpl.java:709)
    at android.view.View.requestLayout(View.java:12675)
    at android.view.View.requestLayout(View.java:12675)
    at android.view.View.requestLayout(View.java:12675)
    at android.view.View.requestLayout(View.java:12675)
    at android.widget.RelativeLayout.requestLayout(RelativeLayout.java:268)
    at android.view.View.requestLayout(View.java:12675)
    at android.view.ViewGroup.addView(ViewGroup.java:3206)
    at android.widget.ViewAnimator.addView(ViewAnimator.java:182)
    at android.view.ViewGroup.addView(ViewGroup.java:3165)
    at android.view.ViewGroup.addView(ViewGroup.java:3145)
    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.run(Native Method)
}   Android.Util.AndroidRuntimeException
```

Two questions:

1. Is this the wrong way to build a dynamic slideshow in Android?
2. How can I fix the error shown above?

Thank you for helping out.

**UPDATE:**
I updated the code to use async based on the answers from tomjen and Simon. Here's the updated method:

```
private Task<Bitmap> GetImageBitmapFromUrl(string url)
    {
        Task<Bitmap> imageBitmap = null;

        url = url.Replace("\"", "");

        RunOnUiThread ( () => {
            using (var webClient = new WebClient())
            {
                var imageBytes = webClient.DownloadDataTaskAsync(url);
                if (imageBytes != null) // && imageBytes.Result.Length > 0
                {
                    try {
                        imageBitmap = BitmapFactory.DecodeByteArrayAsync(imageBytes.Result, 0, imageBytes.Result.Length);
                    } catch (Exception ex) {
                        Log.Error(ex.ToString(), "Couldn't download image");
                    }
                }
            }
        });

        return imageBitmap;
    }
```

Unfortunately, I still get the same error. :(

Answer (score 1):

Don't use the BeginGet/EndGet pattern. It exist only for historic reasons. Use the (much easier) async/await pattern -- this also ensure that the rest happens on the UI thread.

The method you want is DownloadDataAsyncTask in the WebClient class (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.webclient.downloaddatataskasync(v=vs.110).aspx).

Change

```
private Bitmap GetImageBitmapFromUrl(string url)
    {
        Bitmap imageBitmap = null;

        url = url.Replace("\"", "");

        using (var webClient = new WebClient())
        {
            var imageBytes = webClient.DownloadData(url);
            if (imageBytes != null && imageBytes.Length > 0)
            {
                imageBitmap = BitmapFactory.DecodeByteArray(imageBytes, 0, imageBytes.Length);
            }
        }

        return imageBitmap;
    }
```

To something like

```
private async Bitmap GetImageBitmapFromUrl(string url)
    {
        Bitmap imageBitmap = null;

        url = url.Replace("\"", "");

        using (var webClient = new WebClient())
        {
            var imageBytes = await webClient.DownloadDataAsyncTask(url);
            if (imageBytes != null && imageBytes.Length > 0)
            {
                imageBitmap = await BitmapFactory.DecodeByteArrayAsync(imageBytes, 0, imageBytes.Length);
            }
        }

        return imageBitmap;
    }
```

The result of doing so is that everything in the methods, except the IO, gets run on the main thread and that that code simply waits until the IO is done.

You can (and should) do something like that for the other method as well. You can use the DownloadStringAsyncTask method on the WebClient object to do so (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.webclient.downloadstringtaskasync(v=vs.110).aspx).

Comment: Just updated the question to reflect the changes made to the code following your advice. Continues to throw the same exception unfortunately. :(

Answer (score 0):

You can't update UI component from a background Thread. Only the Main Thread (aka UI Thread) can do it:

> Only the original thread that created a view hierarchy can touch its views.

You need to do your network request in a background thread, and then notify your main thread to update the UI. You should take a look at `AsyncTask` or `Handler`.

Comment: Thank you for the advice. I understood that from my initial research. I just didn't know how to go about doing it and was looking for sample code/best practice.

Not being lazy here. I've already spent a few hours on this. I'm really looking for someone to teach me how to fish here.